# Function for Sticky Post on Categories causes issues with 404 behavior

Tags: functions, 404-error, sticky-post

I want to how sticky posts on category pages and I am using a code on my `function.php` file in order to manage it.

The sticky posts are being shown on the category pages, everything is OK.

But with this code, for some reason, when I access to a page that is expected to show a 404 error message, it show the blog page.

**Example:**

If I access to `example.com/fake-page` it shows the same content I would see on `example.com/blog`

Something weird I noted is that if I go to `example.com/real-category/fake-post` or `example.com/fake-category/post`it correctly shows the 404 page as is expected.

My permalink configuration is `/%category%/%postname%`.

**Here is my code:**

```
function get_term_sticky_posts()
{ 
    // First check if we are on a category page, if not, return false
    if ( !is_category() )
        return false;

    // Secondly, check if we have stickies, return false on failure
    $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

    if ( !$stickies )
        return false;

    // OK, we have stickies and we are on a category page, continue to execute. Get current object (category) ID
    $current_object = get_queried_object_id();

    // Create the query to get category specific stickies, just get post ID's though
    $args = [
        'nopaging' => true,
        'post__in' => $stickies,
        'cat' => $current_object,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    return $q;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // IMPORTANT, make sure to target front end only
         && $q->is_main_query() // IMPORTANT, make sure we only target the main query
         && $q->is_category() // Only target category archives
    ) {
        // Check if our function to get term related stickies exists to avoid fatal errors
        if ( function_exists( 'get_term_sticky_posts' ) ) {
            // check if we have stickies
            $stickies = get_term_sticky_posts();

            if ( $stickies ) {
                // Remove stickies from the main query to avoid duplicates
                $q->set( 'post__not_in', $stickies );

                // Check that we add stickies on the first page only, remove this check if you need stickies on all paged pages
                if ( !$q->is_paged() ) {

                    // Add stickies via the the_posts filter
                    add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts ) use ( $stickies )
                    {   
                        $term_stickies = get_posts( ['post__in' => $stickies, 'nopaging' => true] );

                        $posts = array_merge( $term_stickies, $posts );

                        return $posts;
                    }, 10, 1 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I need to find some fix to show the 404 when the page does no exist.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace:

```
if (    !is_admin() // IMPORTANT, make sure to target front end only
     && $q->is_main_query() // IMPORTANT, make sure we only target the main query
     && $q->is_category() // Only target category archives
) {
```

for:

```
if (    !is_admin() // IMPORTANT, make sure to target front end only
     && $q->is_main_query() // IMPORTANT, make sure we only target the main query
     && $q->is_category() // Only target category archives         
     && $q->is_tax(get_query_var ( 'category_name')) // Only target existing category names 
){
```